# select items and transform them in listst: python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, reshape

I have a list like this:

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

and I want to get a list

```
b= a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

I TRIED THIS CODE

```
b = []
for j in range(4):
    for i in xrange(0,len(a),4):
        b.append(a[j])
```

This is the result `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

what shoul id do

Comment: what is the logic behind this transformation? is it sorting or is it something else? You can get to this result in many, many ways.

Comment: ... you want `[x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4] -> [x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4]`?

Comment: Thank you i want x1y1x3y3x2y2x4y4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0, 4.1]
b = a[::2] + a[1::2]
```

gives

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code, iterate over all even elements and then over all odd elements:

```
a = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3', 'x4', 'y4']
b = []

for j in range(2):
    for i in range(j,len(a),2):
        b.append(a[i])

print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to sort the list?

```
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
sorted(a)
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted